# Mean by group with losing any columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, sqldf, spread

I need to calculate the mean per group (i.e, per Coordinates) of the sample table below without losing any of the columns (the real table has over 40,000 rows with different states,location coordinates and type) So this:

| State | Location Coordinates | Type | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| California | West | Debt | 234 | 56 | 79 | 890 | 24 | 29 | 20 | 24 | 26 |
| Nevada | West | Debt | 45 | 54 | 87 | 769 | 54 | 76 | 90 | 87 | 98 |

Would become this :

| State | Location Coordinates | Type | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| West | West | Debt | 234 | 56 | 79 | 890 | 24 | 29 | 20 | 24 | 26 |

When I use aggregate (df <- aggregate(df[,4:length(df)], list(df$Coordinates), mean). It removes the State and City columns.

| Location Coordinates | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| West | 235 | 55 | 83 | 843 | 24 | 29 | 20 | 24 | 26 | Debt | 54 | 769 | 76 | 87 |

And when I use sqldf it averages the year and becomes this:

| State | Location Coordinates | Type | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| West | West | Debt | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 |

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try `aggregate(.~ State + Coordinates + Type, df, mean)`

Answer (score 1):

An option is to first change the 'State'  as 'Coordinates' and then apply the formula method including the grouping variables 'State', 'Coordinates' and 'Type'

```
df$State <- df$`Location Coordinates`
aggregate(.~ State + `Location Coordinates` + Type,
            df, FUN = mean)
```

Comment: So I just realized the column header says Location Coordinates instead of Coordinates. So taking that into account, transform merges the column name to Location.Coordinates. But even when I do aggregate(.~ State + Location.Coordinates + Type,
            transform(df, State = ‘Location Coordinates ‘), FUN = mean) I get NAs across the board and it renames the years to X2002 , X2003.....

Comment: @justcheckingsources you need to match the column name.  If there is space in column name, backquote it insted of `.`

Comment: I did and it says it doesn’t exist. This is what I wrote: aggregate(.~ State + ‘Location Coordinates’+ Type, transform(df, State = ‘Location Coordinates’), FUN = mean) (replacing ‘ with backquotes `)

Comment: @justcheckingsources try the updated solution on my post.  I am assuming the column name is "Location Coordinates"

Comment: @justcheckingsources there is a chance that your column name with spaces is replaced with `Location.Coordinates` by reading the data because `check.names = TRUE` by default in `read.csv/data.frame` construction.  In that case you need `Location.Coordinates' in both transform and aggregate

Comment: @justcheckingsources or when you read the data, use `df <- read.csv('yourfile.text', check.names = FALSE)`

Comment: @justcheckingsources I think it is the `transform` that changes the column name.  Try by assignment instead of transform as in my update

Comment: I triple checked and it doesn’t calculate the mean. It only executes your first line of code by renaming the State to become the names used in Location Coordinates.,

Comment: @justcheckingsources it works with `aggregate(.~ Species, iris, FUN = mean)` though.  So, not clear what you are getting

Answer (score 1):

@akrun: Could this work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Coordinates) %>% 
  summarise(State=Coordinates, Type=Type, across(where(is.numeric), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 0) ## Select even rows
```

Output:

```
# Groups:   Coordinates [1]
  Coordinates State Type  `2002` `2003` `2004` `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010`
  <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 West        West  Debt    140.     55     83   830.     39   52.5     55   55.5     62
```

Comment: You could use `df %>% mutate(State = Coordinates) %>% group_by(State, Coordinates) %>%..` as well.  I am not sure how the OP's values are in 'Coordinates and 'States'.  Based on the input showed it seems to work